# What is the meaning of 開発体制?

Tags: business-japanese

I'm working in an IT environment, my supervisor explained that is not "Development rules" in developing/coding. It is about departments in a company...??? Somehow I still not understand.

I looked at another site (https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E9%96%8B%E7%99%BA%E4%BD%93%E5%88%B6) but unclear too.

This is full sentence:

> 開発体制をきちんと整えもっと仕事が進む状況にできればと思っています。

Could anyone explain for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

開発体制 refers to the structure of your development team. 体制 refers to the structure of an organization, or how people are assigned to a certain project. It has nothing to do with coding (style) guidelines. For example, 5人体制で開発する means five people are assigned to the project, サポート体制を作る means organizing a support team, and 24時間体制で開発する means your team is organized so that your project is developed 24 hours a day.

Answer (score 2):

This 体制 means "system"、"organization".

開発体制をきちんと整える means "We(Our company) properly organize a system for research and development".

Comment: would this be like "research and development" , "R&D" as we say in English? ... reading this I can't tell if this is talking about the "practices" of R&D, or the actual R&D Department....

Comment: Yes, It means "research and development". It says "to organize a system(it may be the R&D Department, though it dosen't say so) for R&D".

Comment: systemというと開発支援ソフトとかのことに思えてしまうのでは…。普通は体制というと人手を揃えることをまずは指すような気がします。

Comment: そうですか。組織と言う意味でsystemという言葉を使ったのですが。